# Histogram with a none

Tags: python, function, histogram

I want this result:

```
*****
*
***
*******
******
******
*
```

and I get this:

```
*****
*
***
*******
******
******
*
None
```

Why has that "none"?

This is my code:

```
def histograma(h):
    for i in h:
        for _ in range(i):
            print ("*", end = "")
        print() 
print(histograma([5,1,3,7,6,6,1]))
```

Comment: In a code running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`histograma` doesn't return anything so it implicitly returns `None`.  Then you call `print(histograma([5,1,3,7,6,6,1]))`, which print's the `None` that was returned.

Change that line to simply `histograma([5,1,3,7,6,6,1])`.

Comment: I cant change that line, because its my teacher who write them

Comment: @LaraMarques Then instead of printing in the function, you're probably expected to return a string that gets printed out after.

Comment: what i need too change?

Comment: @LaraMarques Instead of printing right away, create a long string that represents what you're currently printing out, then return that.

Comment: I dont understand